IIS difference bewteen restarting Application Pool vs Site
New to IIS.
Some background. Recently we updated a webapp folder under the "Default Web Site" with a new version by simply deleting all the old contents in the folder and copying in the new.
This caused an issue for some users who started to get a 404 error, which resolved after a while.
So we are trying to understand how to avoid this.
In IIS I can see that at the "Application Pools", and "Sites/Default Web Site".
Should we recycle/restart the Application Pool, or simply restart the Default Web Site?
Also, how/why would a 404 error if none of the pages were deleted during the update?
Is there some sort of caching (MS Edge browser used by most users) and the IIS web server that would cause this? Or is there an automatic restart/recycle in IIS of relevant components that would explain it started working the next morning?
